# Python scraping and importing as excel file : TypeError: must be real number, not dict

Tags: python, html, excel, win32com

i'm trying in this code, to scrape through a website : https://wish2.ma/product-category/maison-cuisine
and save data to my excel file, the logic is working well as you see, i am able to loop through the pages and extract the data i want, but i get stuck at line 70
First here is my code  :

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import csv
import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import win32com.client as win32

s = HTMLSession()

links = []
for x in range(3,4):
    print(x)
    url = f'https://wish2.ma/product-category/maison-cuisine/page/{x}'
    r = s.get(url)
    items = r.html.find('li.product-type-simple')
    for item in items:
        links.append(item.find('a', first=True).attrs['href'])   

def get_productdata(links):
    r = s.get(link)
    #title = r.html.find('h1', first=True)
    price = r.html.find('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount bdi')[0].full_text
    price2 = r.html.find('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount bdi')[1].full_text
    tag = r.html.find('a[rel=tag]', first=True).full_text
    category =r.html.find('span.ast-woo-product-category')[0].full_text
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find('h1',{'class','product_title'})
    description = soup.find('div',{'class','woocommerce-tabs'}).decode_contents()
    print(title)
    #description = r.html.find('div.woocommerce-tabs')

    product = {
        'title': title.text,
        'price': price.strip(),
        'price2': price2.strip(),
        'tag': tag.strip(),
        'category': category.strip(),
        'description': description
    }
    return product

results = []
#links = get_links()
print(len(links))
ExcelApp = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
ExcelApp.Visible = True

for link in links:
    print(link)
    results.append(get_productdata(link))
    break
wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

header_labels = ['title','price','price2','tag','category','description']

for indx, val in enumerate(header_labels):
        ws.Cells(1, indx + 1).Value = val
row_tracker = 2
column_size = len(header_labels
for result in results:

    ws.Range(
        ws.Cells(row_tracker, 1),
        ws.Cells(row_tracker, column_size)
    ).value=result
    row_tracker += 1
wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'hhhh.xlsx'), 51)
wb.close()
ExcelApp.Quit()
```

this is the error message i get when running the script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kamal\Desktop\amina\scrape_wish.py", line 69, in <module>
    ).value=result
  File "C:\Users\kamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 698, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
TypeError: must be real number, not dict
```

i can't understand it, nor how to solve it, please help me.

Comment: For the worksheet header you set the cells one by oein a loop. You should try the same for the data.

Comment: i already do the same for the data, could you be more precise please

Comment: You set row by row but for each row you try to set a range of cells at once to a dictionary.

Comment: i thought that was the correct logic, any way could you please tell me what to do exaclty because i'm still stuck

Comment: thank's for your help i found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to Michael i found the issue in this line of code,

```
product = {
    'title': title.text,
    'price': price.strip(),
    'price2': price2.strip(),
    'tag': tag.strip(),
    'category': category.strip(),
    'description': description
}
```

i was trying to paste an object here, instead of an array

```
ws.Range(
    ws.Cells(row_tracker, 1),
    ws.Cells(row_tracker, column_size)
).value=result
```

so i made an array like this one

```
product = [title.text,price.strip(),price2.strip(),tag.strip(),category.strip(),description]
```

and i set a sleeping time to let the excel app save before closing

```
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Why do you need a timer, out of curiosity?

Comment: to set time between saving the file and closing the ExcelApp, i had an error before so it helped.